# Make (Dynamically Generate) Textarea Attribute Autofocus & Required

Tags: jquery, html

I was trying to make the textarea generated dynamically autofocus when clicked it's parent Div. But it is not working. The same happens with required and maxlenght. I appreciate any help :)

I try writing in the **tag** *autofocus, required and required='required'*. And therefore in JQuery I used **focus()** and **focusin()**; But nothing happen.

**HTML**

```
    <p class='p_usuarios' onClick='read_chat_messages()'> /*PARENT*/
    ...
    <textarea class='textarea_chat' spellcheck='false'></textarea>
    <input type='button' class='send_chat_message' onClick='send_chat_message()' value='Bidali!'/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   function read_chat_messages() (){

    $(".textarea_chat").focus(); /*focusin();*/
    var value= $(".textarea_chat").val();
    ...

   }
```

Comment: Please add the jQuery code that you tried to help you correct any mistakes

Comment: Your HTML is a bit hard to follow since you've omitted a decent chunk. Can you provide a bit more detail/ less abbreviated code?

Comment: Regardless of my HTML code, what it should be? (I skip it because I consider it would not change much the output )

Comment: The issue is that I read many posts posted 7 years ago +- and said that textarea doesn't accept those attributes, so I am looking for an alternative to use JQuery or JavaScript indistinctly :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent-selector').click( () => {
  $('.textarea_chat').focus()
})
```

I'd be worried about using a class target with `.focus()` as if 2 or more elements share that class I don't *know* what'd happen! It'd be better to use an ID either instead of or alongside the class (i.e `#chat_area`) UNLESS you have a specific reason not to

Comment: Hi there! Only the class is associated with the Textarea. It could not turn out well otherwise xD

Comment: This event does not autofocus the element, only it is triggered when you focus it.https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: I was wrong.  The doc says the following: "Bind an event handler to the "focus" JavaScript event, **or** trigger that event on an element."

Answer (score 0):

Every textarea must follow a input type submit within the  tags, in order to the display the required alert event.  :S

The issue with Autofocus is that it should be set a minimum Timeout in order to Focus the Element. The Browser needs time to perform it, I understand it in this way. The Autofocus Attribute is not working inside HTML textarea tags.